# Is there an elegant way to type erase a Publisher to Future in Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a API call that returns a Future and I need to combine it with another Future which I get from executing a query on a local DB and reconcile both. I am trying to find a more elegant way to do this without having to create another Future, because I do not want to type erase to AnyPublisher. This is a simplified code sample below.

```
func fetchLocalDB() -> Future<[Result], Error> {
    
    return Future<[Result], Error> {
        
        promise in
        self.managedObjectContext.publisher(for: Result.self)
            .sink { completion in /*promise(.failure())*/ }
            receiveValue: { results in
                
                promise(.success(results))
            }
            .store(in: &self.anyCancellables)
    }
}

func fetchRemote() throws -> Future<[ResultData], Error> {
    
    return Future<[ResultData], Error> {
        promise in
        
        APICall()
            .sink { completion in /*promise(.failure())*/ }
            .receiveValue: { resultsData in
                
                //process resultData, promise(.failure(error))
                promise(.success(processedResultsData))
            }
            .store(in: &self.anyCancellables)
    }
}

func reconcile() {
    
    fetchRemote()
        .combineLatest(fetchLocalDB())
        .tryMap({/*reconcile data here*/})
}
```

I could use the map operator and type erase to AnyPublisher like below, but I would prefer having a Future to work with instead.

```
func fetchLocalDB() -> AnyPublisher<[Result], Error> {
    self.managedObjectContext.publisher(for: Result.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func fetchRemote() throws -> AnyPublisher<[ResultData], Error> {
   APICall()
       .tryMap: { resultsData throws -> [ResultData] in

            //process resultData, throw error
            return processedResultsData
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, might help if you could provide basic types such as Result so that the code compiles.

Comment: Result is an Entity from DB, ResultData is the decoded data from API call and I'd save the data as Result in the DB. For instance, the API I call returns a list of Books, which I call BooksData, and I save them in my CoreData as the Book entity. I can't give the API and the code is not rigorous. My question is like this, is there some way I can type erase one Future(on which I perform operations) to a Future, instead of AnyPublisher

Comment: What error are you seeing? `CombineLatest` requires only the failure to match, so `fetchRemote().combineLatest(fetchLocalDB())` should work without erasing to `AnyPublisher`. But also, why the objection to erase to `AnyPublisher`?